# I have integrated yahoo into iphone app but i am getting error:400 bad request

Tags: iphone, ios

I have to access social information for the logged-in user.i have used following link. http://developer.yahoo.com/social/sdk/objectivec

i have used send request method to get user information.
but i am getting following error message

<

```
?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<error xmlns='http://yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng' 
       xml:lang='en'>
    <description>400 Bad Request</description>
    <detail>400 Error : syntax error, unexpected &apos;(&apos; at &quot;*(*null)&quot;
```

can any one help me?

thank you in advance.

Comment: How to integrate OpenID and google credentials into iphone app?

Answer (score 0):

The Yahoo Web server (running the Web site) thinks that the data stream sent by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) was 'malformed' i.e. did not respect the HTTP protocol completely. So the Web server was unable to understand the request and process it. so make sure you are sending the well structured request.

Based on your commented:
http://nullinfo.wordpress.com/oauth-yahoo/
http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-make-request.html

You should understand how to make request with oauth, first read that and later if you could not succeed, ask again.

Comment: i found that this error is because i am getting  error "OAuth Verifier value is null".i have loged GUID it is also null.